# Read all files in a directory and count them based on their content

Tags: python

I want to load all files in present in a directory and count files having + and -

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re
import sys

def run(body):

    bang = len(re.findall('\n\s{,1}!', body))
    minus = len(re.findall('\n\s{,1}-[^-]', body))
    plus = len(re.findall('\n\s{,1}\+[^\+]', body))

    rs = "(+:%d) (-:%d) (!:%d)" % (plus, minus, bang)
    return rs


f = open("", 'r')
a = f.read()

print(sys.argv[1], run(a))
```

In 1000 files only one file is generating the output. The other files lead to an error called

> Too many args

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate all files in folder and check the content of them. Try the following script:

```
import os
import re
import sys

def run(body):

    bang = len(re.findall('\n\s{,1}!', body))
    minus = len(re.findall('\n\s{,1}-[^-]', body))
    plus = len(re.findall('\n\s{,1}\+[^\+]', body))

    rs = "(+:%d) (-:%d) (!:%d)" % (plus, minus, bang)
    return rs

for root, _, files in os.walk(".", topdown=False):
   for name in files:
      f = open("os.path.join(root, name)", 'r')
      a = f.read()
      print("%s" % run(a))
```